Is there a statement where Jesus says I am God, worship me?
I know this question is a bit stupid, but unfortunately it is parroted by many Muslims and Muslim apologists. How can this sentence be refuted once and for all by taking some Scriptures from the Gospel?

Not a stupid question at all just not the sort of question that fits this site. ie: it is looking for a Scripture as opposed to giving one for examination.

This question may be better on Christianity SX.

wrote an article on this a while back answering islam: https://steppingstonesintl.com/where-does-jesus-ever-say-i-am-the-son-of-god

This question is likely to be closed because it is searching of a text.  However, in the spirit of helpfulness let me provide some.
There are a very few texts that command worship of God such as:

Ps 29:2 - Ascribe to the LORD the glory due His name; worship the LORD in the splendor of His holiness.
1 Chron 16:29 - Ascribe to the LORD the glory due His name; bring an offering and come before Him. Worship the LORD in the splendor of His holiness;
Josh 24:14 - Now, therefore, fear the LORD and serve Him in sincerity and truth; cast aside the gods your fathers served beyond the Euphrates and in Egypt, and serve the LORD.
Matt 4:10 - “Away from Me, Satan!” Jesus declared. “For it is written: ‘Worship the Lord your God and serve Him only.’ ”
Luke 4:8 - But Jesus answered, “It is written: ‘Worship the Lord your God and serve Him only.’ ”
Rev 19:10 - So I fell at his feet to worship him. But he told me, “Do not do that! I am a fellow servant with you and your brothers who rely on the testimony of Jesus. Worship God! For the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy.”

However, the more important command in the Bible is to Love the LORD God - because those who love God worship him naturally:

Deut 6:5 - And you shall love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength.
Deut 11:1 - You shall therefore love the LORD your God and always keep His charge, His statutes, His ordinances, and His commandments.
Deut 11:13 - So if you carefully obey the commandments I am giving you today, to love the LORD your God and to serve Him with all your heart and with all your soul,
Deut 11:22 - For if you carefully keep all these commandments I am giving you to follow—to love the LORD your God, to walk in all His ways, and to hold fast to Him—
Deut 19:9 - and if you carefully keep all these commandments I am giving you today, loving the LORD your God and walking in His ways at all times, then you are to add three more cities to these three.
Deut 30:6 - And the LORD your God will circumcise your heart and the heart of your offspring, so that you will love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul, that you may live.
Deut 30:16 - For I am commanding you today to love the LORD your God, to walk in His ways, and to keep His commandments, statutes, and ordinances, so that you may live and increase, and the LORD your God may bless you in the land that you are entering to possess.
Deut 30:20 - and that you may love the LORD your God, obey Him, and hold fast to Him. For He is your life, and He will prolong your life in the land that the LORD swore to give to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.”
Josh 22:5 - But be very careful to observe the commandment and the law that Moses the servant of the LORD gave you: to love the LORD your God, to walk in all His ways, to keep His commandments, to hold fast to Him, and to serve Him with all your heart and with all your soul.”
Josh 23:11 - Therefore watch yourselves carefully, that you love the LORD your God.
Matt 22:37 - Jesus declared, “ ‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’
Mark 12:30 - Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’
Luke 10:27 - He answered, “ ‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength and with all your mind’ and ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ ”
etc, etc - there are many more.

This is what makes Bible Christianity distinct from anything else - it begins with love to God and our fellow humans and that results in worshiping the origin of all love, God, because "God is Love", 1 John 4:8, 16.
APPENDIX - Jesus personal claims to divinity

Woman at the well


John 4:25, 26 - The woman said, “I know that Messiah” (called Christ)
“is coming. When He comes, He will explain everything to us.” Jesus
answered, “The one speaking to you, I Am.”

This “I Am” declaration serves a dual function:

to positively identify Himself as Messiah
to affirm that Jesus is the “I Am” of the OT (see above OT references).

Thus, in the incident recorded in John 4, Jesus is introduced as a man who is tired and hungry (V6), but who is actually, God.

John 5 - Healing at the Pool of Bethesda

The healing of the man at the pool of Bethesda followed by an extended discussion between the Jews and Jesus in John 5 is a special event where Jesus makes repeated claims about His divinity and equality with the Father; thus, it deserves special attention.
[NOTE: Jesus performed seven miracles on the Sabbath: Mark 1:21-28, 29-31, 3:1-6, John 9:1-16, Luke 13:10-17, 14:1-6, John 5:1-18. In several of these, Jesus was accused of breaking the Sabbath and had to defend His actions. The differences in His defense are significant. In Mark 3:1-6, John 9:1-16, Luke 13:10-17, Jesus defends His actions on the Sabbath by essentially claiming He was doing good, etc.]
However, in John 5, Jesus heals the man at Bethesda on Sabbath; but, Jesus makes no attempt to defend Himself by claiming that He was excused because He was doing good. Rather He claimed that this was part of His regular job of working continuously just as the Father does (compare Col 1:17) and thus was not guilty of Sabbath breaking.
This is significant; Jesus’ defense in John 5 was essentially His divinity as He states several times in the subsequent discussion in John 5.  Thus, Jesus' defense is unique here - He claims equality with the Father and the need to uphold the universe (Col 1:17), and thus, was not guilty of breaking the Sabbath.
The great problem that the Jews had in John 5, against which Jesus defends Himself, appears to have at least two facets:

God (as they understood Him) is Almighty, Grand, Majestic and distant (despite the above). It was precisely this idea that the Gospel of John was written to dispel because in its opening prologue, we read: (John 1:18) - No one has ever seen God, but the one and only God, the One being in the bosom of the Father, has made Him known. Compare v1 where the Word is God.
Jesus calls God the Father, “my Father” (V17), ie, His personal Father making Jesus equal with God. [I pause to note, and am surprised to observe that the Jews did not object to this based on strict monotheism!!] This was acknowledged and unchallenged.
Jesus then goes on to say specifically in what aspects He was equal with the Father:
V17 - Both the Father and Jesus must “work” continuously (See Col 1:17)
V17, 18 - Jesus claims the Father as his own personal Father
V19 - The Father and Jesus work together in complete unity (not unison)
V21, 26 - The Father and Jesus both have life in Themselves and can raise people from the dead at will
V22 - The Father has committed all judgement to the Son
V23 - All must honor the Son as they honor the Father
V24, 25 – Jesus’ “word” is the key to eternal life

Jesus then summons legal evidence that His testimony about Himself (as outline above) is valid under Jewish law because:

V31-38 - He has a second, very weighty, witness in His Father.
V39, 40 - Jesus claims to be the fulfillment of the Scriptures as Messiah
V41-47 - Jesus comes in the Name of the Father and they do not believe Jesus; this, despite the fact that they believed other people who come in their own name.


John 8, Multiple Claims

John 8 is also significant because there are multiple claims made by Jesus:

V12 – “I am the Light of the world” (Compare John 1:9, 9:5) - a direct allusion to Ps 27:1, “The LORD is my light and my salvation”, and, Micah 7:8 “the LORD will be my light.”
V23, 24 - Then He told them, “You are from below; I am from above. You are of this world; I am not of this world. That is why I told you that you would die in your sins. For unless you believe that I am, you will die in your sins.”
V28 - So Jesus said, “When you have lifted up the Son of Man, then you will know that I am, and that I do nothing on My own, but speak exactly what the Father has taught Me.
V58, 59 - “Truly, truly, I tell you,” Jesus declared, “before Abraham was born, I am!” At this, they picked up stones to throw at Him. ...

Thus, Jesus makes a triple claim to be the great “I AM” of the OT in this chapter.  Further, Jesus’ claim about being the “I Am” of the OT is couched in three ways: In the past (V58), in the present (V24), and in the future (V28).  That is, Jesus always was, is, and always will be the great “I Am”.  Compare the same title of God in Rev 1:8 - “I am the Alpha and the Omega,” says the Lord God, “who is, and who was, and who is to come, the Almighty.”

John 10 – the Good Shepherd

V11, 14, 15 “I am the good Shepherd … I am the good Shepherd … there will be one flock and One Shepherd.” (Compare Ps 23:1, “The LORD is my Shepherd”.)

V24-27, So the Jews gathered around Him and demanded, “How long will
You keep us in suspense? If You are the Christ, tell us plainly.” “I
already told you,” Jesus replied, “but you did not believe.  The works
I do in My Father’s name testify on My behalf.  But because you are
not My sheep, you refuse to believe.  My sheep listen to My voice; I
know them, and they follow Me. (Compare 1 Peter 5:4.)

V30, 31, 33, “I and the Father are one.” At this, the Jews again picked up stones to stone Him. ... “We are not stoning You for any good work,” said the Jews, “but for blasphemy, because You, who are a man, declare Yourself to be God.”
This claim that “I and the Father are one” appears to be an allusion to the famous “Shema” of Deut 6:4, “Hear, O Israel, the LORD our God, the LORD is One.”  This explains the Jews’ accusation about a man claiming to be God as blasphemous.

Peter's Confession


Matt 16:16, 17 - Simon Peter answered, “You are the Christ, the Son of
the living God.” Jesus replied, “Blessed are you, Simon son of Jonah!
For this was not revealed to you by flesh and blood, but by My Father
in heaven."

Note the dual title of (1) Christ/Messiah, and, (2) The Son of God

Trial before the Sanhedrin


Mark 14:61-64 - Again the high priest questioned Him, “Are You the
Christ, the Son of the Blessed One?” “I am” said Jesus, “and you will
see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of Power and coming with
the clouds of heaven.” At this, the high priest tore his clothes and
declared, “Why do we need any more witnesses? You have heard the
blasphemy. What is your verdict?” And they all condemned Him as
deserving of death.

In this instance, Jesus effectively claims several things, namely:

That He was the Christ/Messiah
That He was The Son of God
That He was The “I Am”
That He was The Son of Man (see Dan 7:13)
That He was the legitimate King of Israel, both literal and spiritual
… and thus, that He was both fully human and fully divine

Note that claiming to be a human messiah was nothing new. However, explicitly claiming to be both human (a son of man) and divine (“The Son of Man”, see Dan 7:13, and “The Son of God”, compare Dan 3:25) and Messiah all at once, was (to them) quite blasphemous; but only if it was not true!  This was confirmed by the High Priest illegally tearing is robes as a symbol of his horror of blasphemy.

Arrest in the Garden

John 18 records the arrest of Jesus in the Garden and the exchange between Him and the mob:

4 Jesus, knowing all that was coming upon Him, stepped forward and
asked them, “Whom are you seeking?”
5 “Jesus of Nazareth,” they answered. Jesus said, “I Am.” And Judas
His betrayer was standing there with them. 6 When Jesus said, “I am,”
they drew back and fell to the ground.
7 So He asked them again, “Whom are you seeking?” “Jesus of Nazareth,”
they answered.
8 “I told you that I Am.” Jesus replied.

In this instance, the “I Am” of Jesus clearly serves a dual function:

to positively identify Himself as the Jesus of Nazareth whom they are seeking to arrest
to affirm that Jesus is the “I Am” of the OT, as confirmed by the fact that this declaration of His divinity made the arresting mob fall backwards.


The Thomas' Confession


John 20:28 - Thomas said to him, ‘My Lord and my God.’ [literally, The
Lord of me and the God (ho theos) of me].

Jesus then commended Thomas for finally arriving at this conclusion (contrast Acts 10:25, 26, Rev 19:10, 22:8, 9).

+1 for the spirit of helpfulness. But I'm surprised you answered the question and also voted to close it. :-)

@DanFefferman - agreed!!  I try to abide by the rules but I do not agree with some of the rules, especially that one.  [PS: did you remember to actually vote?]

I abstained. I think the question has already been dealt with adequately.

'Abstaining' is often a case of 'sitting on the fence'. Up-voted +1.

+1 for @Dottard's comprehensive hermeneutical answer in the face of a very common assertion. There's also Philippians 2:5-7 ESV: "Have this mind among yourselves, which is yours in Christ Jesus, who, though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with God a thing to be grasped, but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant, being born in the likeness of men." Hebrews 1:3a ESV reads: "He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power." Why not demonstrate hermeneutically sound answers to questions?
